Cognito & Google sign in: pass custom user attribute
We need your help. We struggle to pass a custom user attribute with federated sign-in (Google) in Cognito.
We have 5 usertypes and we need to set them during the registration.
It works fine with the direct sign-up via email but not with Google:
await signUp({
    username: email,
    password,
    options: {
      userAttributes: {
        email,
        phone_number,
        'custom:userType': 'usertype1',
      },
      autoSignIn: true,
      validationData,
    },
  });

With Google sign in we can only do this:
  async handleGoogleSignIn() {
try {
  await signInWithRedirect({
      provider: 'Google',//@ts-ignore
      customState: JSON.stringify({'custom:userType': 'usertype2'}),
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error signing in with Google:', error);
}

}
and then, using listener "hub" from amplify we can update the user attribute.
const hubListenerCancel = Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload }) => {
  switch (payload.event) {
    case "customOAuthState":
      const attribute = JSON.parse(payload.data)// this will be customState provided o
      this.updateUserCustomAttribute(attribute['custom:userType'])
      break;
  }
  hubListenerCancel();
});

But this does not work properly.
1 It does not trigger our lambda (to add a user in the DB) and after login, we have no access to the attribute we set (it's accessible only after user login second time).
Please, help to solve this.
